# OptaPlanner domainAccessType Gizmo

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner

I'm trying to use `<domainAccessType>GIZMO</domainAccessType>` in my solver config.

It seems to get fast access with most of my variables, but it throws an exception for variables in my `@PlanningSolution`:

```
17:30:17.863 [main        ] TRACE     Model annotations parsed for solution VehicleRoutingSolution:
17:30:17.866 [main        ] TRACE         Entity Standstill:
17:30:17.866 [main        ] TRACE             Shadow variable nextVisit (Fast access with generated bytecode)
17:30:17.866 [main        ] TRACE         Entity Visit:
17:30:17.866 [main        ] TRACE             Genuine variable previousStandstill (Fast access with generated bytecode)
17:30:17.866 [main        ] TRACE             Shadow variable arrivalTime (Fast access with generated bytecode)
17:30:17.866 [main        ] TRACE             Shadow variable subShift (Fast access with generated bytecode)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Member (solverStatus) of class (org.acme.domain.VehicleRoutingSolution) is not public and domainAccessType is GIZMO.
Maybe put the annotations onto the public getter of the field.
Maybe use domainAccessType REFLECTION instead of GIZMO.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.gizmo.GizmoMemberDescriptor.<init>(GizmoMemberDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.gizmo.GizmoSolutionOrEntityDescriptor.getFieldsToSolutionFieldToMemberDescriptorMap(GizmoSolutionOrEntityDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.gizmo.GizmoSolutionOrEntityDescriptor.<init>(GizmoSolutionOrEntityDescriptor.java:39)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.gizmo.GizmoSolutionClonerImplementor.lambda$createCloneSolutionRun$6(GizmoSolutionClonerImplementor.java:294)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.gizmo.GizmoSolutionClonerImplementor.createCloneSolutionRun(GizmoSolutionClonerImplementor.java:293)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.gizmo.GizmoSolutionClonerImplementor.defineClonerFor(GizmoSolutionClonerImplementor.java:157)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.gizmo.GizmoSolutionClonerImplementor.createClonerFor(GizmoSolutionClonerImplementor.java:200)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.gizmo.GizmoSolutionClonerFactory.build(GizmoSolutionClonerFactory.java:31)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.initSolutionCloner(SolutionDescriptor.java:601)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.afterAnnotationsProcessed(SolutionDescriptor.java:545)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.buildSolutionDescriptor(SolutionDescriptor.java:126)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolutionDescriptor(DefaultSolverFactory.java:160)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:133)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolver(DefaultSolverFactory.java:87)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.validateSolverFactory(DefaultSolverManager.java:69)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.<init>(DefaultSolverManager.java:58)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager.create(SolverManager.java:111)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager.create(SolverManager.java:84)
```

Here is the Planning Solution I'm using:

```
@PlanningSolution
class VehicleRoutingSolution {

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "visitRange")
    lateinit var visitList: List<Visit>

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "subShiftRange")
    lateinit var subShiftList: List<SubShift>


    private var solverStatus: SolverStatus? = null
    fun getSolverStatus(): SolverStatus? {
        return solverStatus
    }
    fun setSolverStatus(solverStatus: SolverStatus?) {
        this.solverStatus = solverStatus
    }

    private var score: SimpleLongScore? = null
    @PlanningScore
    fun getScore(): SimpleLongScore? {
        return score
    }
    fun setScore(score: SimpleLongScore?) {
        this.score = score
    }

    // No-arg constructor required for OptaPlanner
    constructor() {}

    constructor(subShiftList: List<SubShift>, visitList: List<Visit>) {
        this.subShiftList = subShiftList
        this.visitList = visitList
    }

}
```

The `solverStatus` doesn't even have an annotation, so I don't understand why it's complaining about that.

And oddly, if I put my `score` variable section above my `solverStatus` section, it complains about `score` not being `public` when the getter clearly is.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: If you're using Quarkus, GIZMO is on by default - there is no need to explicitly turn it on. But if works without turning it on in Quarkus, it should work with turning it on too (should be the exact same result). Is that the case?

Comment: If I add ```<domainAccessType>GIZMO</domainAccessType>``` to ```solverConfig.xml``` and run with Quarkus then it does not run. So that tells me Quarkus is having issues as well and just resorting to ```REFLECTION```. At least when I run it with ```REFLECTION``` I'm getting ```pretty fast access with LambdaMetafactory``` and maybe that's good enough. I guess it's just odd/disturbing that it's complaining about ```Member```s being ```private``` when they are indeed ```public```. It may not be worth going down the rabbit hole though.

Comment: optaplanner-quarkus doesn't mind if the members are private - it can still generate virtual getters at build time to workaround that. This sounds like a bug, what version of optaplanner are you using?

Comment: ```<quarkus.platform.version>2.5.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>``` ```<optaplanner.version>8.14.0.Final</optaplanner.version>```

Comment: Would you mind creating an issue for it? https://issues.redhat.com/projects/PLANNER We'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to reproduce in Quarkus. See https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/technology/kotlin-quarkus for an example of using OptaPlanner with Kotlin in Quarkus. I tested changing the the fields of [TimeTable](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/blob/stable/technology/kotlin-quarkus/src/main/kotlin/org/acme/kotlin/schooltimetabling/domain/TimeTable.kt) to private, and it works as expected.

Outside of Quarkus, this behaviour is expected. When domain access type GIZMO is used, member accessors and a custom solution cloner is generated for the domain. The custom solution cloner requires all fields to be public; public getters/setters are not used since they are not guaranteed to be simple (they could do validation checks that throw an exception, or modify other fields).

Comment: Yeah, I don't have a lot of confidence that my environment is setup properly at this point to work with Quarkus. It's confusing because I now have three areas where I'm altering configurations. I get this message, ```WARN  [io.qua.run.log.LoggingSetupRecorder] (Quarkus Main Thread) Log level TRACE for category 'org.optaplanner' set below minimum logging level DEBUG, promoting it to DEBUG```. I also can't get Trace logging enabled despite it being set in ```application.properties``` and ```logback.xml```. Settings in ```solverConfig.xml``` also conflict such as ```environmentMode```. Confusing.